# Logrotate Error: Unable to open ... for compression

Tags: linux, logrotate

When using logrotate from a cronjob, I am getting this erros:

```
error: unable to open /var/log/mylog.1  for compression
```

Does any one know what does it mean and how can I fix it ?

Comment: You should have added your logrotate configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that `/var/log/mylog.1` does not exist or the permissions/ownership do not allow that file to be compressed.  Check the permissions/ownership with `ls -l /var/log/mylog*`.

Answer (score 3):

You're going to need to get more information.

Does the file exist, and does the user running cron have permission to read it?:

```
ls -l /var/log/mylog.1
```

See if logrotate can give more information. It should have a verbose flag you can turn on with '-v'.

Answer (score 1):

If the file exists, and the permissions are ok, then a cause can be that the file is open when you try to compress it. In order to avoid that, you can add the following line to your `/etc/logrotate.conf`:

```
delaycompress
```

Answer (score 0):

I just hit this error myself. Summary: it was a conflict between `logrotate` and a postrotate script I'd written, where in certain circumstances my `logrotate` script would delete the just-moved log file before it was compressed. Although you'd think that `logrotate` would compress the file and **then** run the post-rotate script, it actually does it in the other order. Hence this error message.

Since `logrotate` directly manages the file that the question shows as missing, I can't think of anything else that might cause this problem, unless there's something really strange about the file permissions (e.g. writeable and not readable).